# SQL - Select all person whose "firstName lastName" contain a name

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database table "person" with two columns firstName and lastName. Now I want to select all the persons whose "firstName lastName" contains a given name. How can i do it with a SQL query?

Example:

Person x with firstName: A B and lastName: C

Person y with firstName: A and lastName: B C

Person z with firstName: A B and lastName: C D

All of these persons should be shown in output if the query is with a criteria that the fullName (firstName lastName) contain B C

The table was designed that it does not have fullName column.

Comment: Please show at least  ERD ,OR Table structure Please Read 
[How To ask question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What i did is i select all of person from database and created a filter in source code. The class Person is mapped to Table Person and i created a method to get the full name and did followed checking:  if(person.getFullName().toLowerCase().contains(name.toLowerCase())) { foundPersons.add(person); } it works also but i think it is not the effective solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the following would do what you want:

```
where concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) like concat('%', replace($search, ' ', '%'), '%')
```

This replaces the spaces in the search term with wildcards, so it could conceivably match a few other situations.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that I followed 100% but it seems like you want to select every person whose name contains both B and C.  If that's the case I'd go with something like this:

```
SELECT (firstName, lastName) as FullName from person where 
(firstName like '%B%' OR lastName like '%B%') and 
(firstName like'%C%' or lastName like '%C%');
```

for a more general solution involving a single string such as 'AL' go with

```
select * from person where (firstName like 
'%$stringVariable%' OR lastName like '%$stringVariable');
```

Comment: It was just a example and you don't know how long the given name is. What i need is a general solution.

Comment: alright, if you only need to look for one string at a time for instance any name containing "AL" you could still use the solution I gave, you'd simply switch the B and C to a variable.  I'll edit my answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

I Think that is what you asked

```
SELECT First_Name+' '+Last_Name As Full_Name
From Table_xyz where
First_Name in(a,ab, b)
And Last_Name in (b,c,bc,cd)
```